# Put Objects Inside a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

So I have a class called `Note` and I need to put every `Note` inside a JComboBox.

Each Note has a `String id` and a `String title`. The `title` is being shown to the user, and the `id` is being used in the backend.

I've written a custom renderer to make this work, but I am getting compiler error: **error: Note cannot be converted to String**

Here is the code:

```
//Inside of the GUI class

    cmbNotes.setRenderer(new NoteListCellRenderer());

 //Populate combo box with the title of each note
        NoteManager.notes.forEach((id, note) -> { //For-each loop

            if (!note.isOpen()) {
                cmbNotes.addItem(note); //ERROR: Note cannot be converted to String
            }

        });
```

Here is my custom renderer:

```
//In the same file as GUI, but outside of the GUI class

class NoteListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof Note) {
            value = ((Note) value).getTitle();
        }
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @RiaanNel There is no exception, it is a compiler error and won't even let me compile my program.

Comment: How do you declare the JComboBox (cmbNotes)?  Specifically, what is the generic type parameter?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem(E)

Comment: @RiaanNel Turns out the type was set to String by default and I figured out how to fix that issue. I posted my answer below. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Riann Nel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5917104/riaan-nel) for helping me to solve this problem.

I had created the JComboBox through the design, not through code.

The design by default sets the `Type Parameters` to `String` so I went in the design and clicked on the code section on the right then changed the `Type Parameters` to `<Note>`.

I also had to add a default constructor in my `Note` class.